# Change fullCalendar resourceTimeGridDay view row height

Tags: css, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I have integrated fullcalendar in my react project, and if I change the slotMinTime and slotMaxTime property the row changes it's height. If I reduce the number of hours to display each slot gets bigger in size and I am not able to get it back to it's actual size. I have used contentHeight and aspectRatio but they don't seem to be working either. Please help.

```
<FullCalendar
        schedulerLicenseKey="CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives"
        ref={calendarRef}
        plugins={[
            momentTimezonePlugin,
            ScrollgridPlugin,
            resourceTimelinePlugin,
            resourceTimeGridPlugin,
            googleCalendarPlugin,
            interactionPlugin
        ]}
        timeZone="America/New_York"
        height="100%"
        // aspectRatio={5}
        droppable={true}
        headerToolbar={{
            left : '',
            center : '',
            right : ''
        }}
        dayMinWidth={250}
        nowIndicator={true}
        slotEventOverlap={false}
        slotDuration="00:15:00"
        slotMinTime="07:00:00"
        slotMaxTime="19:00:00"
        slotLabelInterval="00:15"
        slotLabelFormat={{
            hour : 'numeric',
            minute : '2-digit',
            hour12 : true
        }}
        initialView="resourceTimeGridDay"
        editable={true}
        eventResourceEditable={true}
        allDaySlot={false}
        selectable={true}
        selectMirror={true}
        dayMaxEvents={true}
        resources={resources}
        events={appointments}
        slotLabelContent={SlotComp}
        resourceLabelContent={data => RenderResourceContent(data, setActiveProviderView)
        }
        resourceOrder="title"
        weekends={true}
        eventContent={data => (
            <EventComp
                data={data}
                appointments={appointments}
                apiLoading={apiLoading}
                addAppointmentToUpdate={addAppointmentToUpdate}
                addAppointmentToDuplicate={addAppointmentToDuplicate}
                addBreakAppointment={addBreakAppointment}
                updateAppointmentStatus={updateAppointmentStatus}
                showRecurringLoadingNotification={
                    showRecurringLoadingNotification
                }
                appointmentDetailsToggle={appointmentDetailsToggle}
                getPatientDetails={getPatientDetails}
            />
        )}
        selectConstraint="businessHours"
        eventConstraint="businessHours"
        select={newEventSelected}
        eventDrop={eventDropped}
        eventResize={eventResizeStopped}
        eventChange={eventChanged}
    />
```

This is how it look if I don't specify min and max time
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R58BdUJAt11G2vZ0bbsvOJaPYpKPj33p/view?usp=sharing

after I specify
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l6opSZClV0sz3kgVEQV6ioIyor-YIKZt/view?usp=sharing

Row height gets to 80px otherwise it's just 40px

Comment: `If I reduce the number of hours to display each slot gets bigger in size`...not sure what you mean, I have not experienced this with fullCalendar. Can you perhaps provide a couple of comparison screenshots so we can see what you mean, and also show precisely what settings you changed (and what values you used for those settings in each case) in order to for the difference to occur? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah sure, I have edited the question. You can check. Thanks

Comment: Using the relevant bits of your code I tried to recreate the scenario (using vanilla fullCalendar as I don't know react, but the underlying functionality is the same) and got this outcome: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRrdOQY . The squashed calendar seems to be the result of the height: 100% rule. Do you have some other CSS and elements which controls the height of the container in which the calendar is situated? That might be important for this scenario.

Comment: If we remove the height: 100% option, the calendar looks ok and the slots are not stretched: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/LYxmOme .

Comment: If we keep the height, and also have an arbitrarily-large fixed-height container to wrap the calendar, then the slots also look ok (although there's a big empty area at the bottom of the grid): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/mdRLqKz . In short...I can't reproduce your issue. I notice from the screenshots you also seem to have a custom theme in use. So your issue is likely to be because of the container round the calendar and the CSS controlling it, or some CSS in your theme, or a combination of the two.

Comment: The element inspector in your browser's Developer Tools should tell you what rule(s) are being applied to the grid rows, and where the rule(s) come from. That would hopefully be a shortcut to locating the relevant code.

Comment: I have specified styling for some elements but not the row height. What I have observed is that these rows get adjusted to fill up the complete height of the calendar body container. "fc-timegrid-body" is the class of that div, and its height remain the same even if I specify min and max time, thus increasing the height of each row.
I can override it using CSS but then events do not fit properly in the slots

Comment: As I've shown in my CodePens, with the default theme that doesn't happen. Can you switch your app to the default theme and see if the issue persists? That would narrow it down a bit. If you want further help, we'll need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - i.e. enough code to reliably be able to reproduce the issue ourselves.